# Form reset for all fields except one Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to find a way to to exclude one field input in my form that is disabled and contains the value of a users ID number

I would like to know how I can tweak   `this.$refs.form.reset();` because it works perfectly but it clears EVERYTHING and I wish to contain the ID value and resets the rest of the fields like `name` `surname` `age` `income` etc

The reason why I the ID is important is that the user gives this in a sign-up step at the start and this form that I am talking about is located somewhere else to complete his profile I don't want to ask the user again to type his ID in again.

If anyone knows how to accomplish this it would be a great help

Comment: A workaround could be splitting forms into two. You can reset one and the other one can remain the same.

Comment: there is only this form on the complete profile page - the other one mentioned is located somewhere else when the user signs up (they are already two forms) the one with that I want to exclude ID form `this.$refs.form.reset();` is quite important @Eldar

Comment: Another workaround is to save the user ID, clear the form, then restore the user ID through the `v-model` on the user ID input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reset` method of the form simply looks at all the inputs bound to it and resets each one within a loop then empties the error bag, observe:

```js
reset (): void {
  this.inputs.forEach(input => input.reset())
  this.resetErrorBag()
},
```

There's no reason you can't do the same, except for when they're disabled:

```js
resetForm() {
  this.$refs.form.inputs.forEach(input => {
    if (!input.disabled) {
      input.reset()
    }
  })
  this.$refs.form.resetErrorBag() // necessary to remove validation errors after the field values are removed
}
```

Then you can call that function (against your Vue instance, not your VForm) with `this.resetForm()` and it should work out the way you want.

Disclaimer: Can't test it at the moment. `input.disabled` may not be readily available and may require further inspection of the `input` element.